# First argument label in Swift method

Tags: swift, signature, method-signature

Which one of these methods follows the Swift ideology?

- `func addChapter(_ chapter: Chapter)`
- `func add(chapter chapter: Chapter)`
- `func add(_ chapter: Chapter)`

Comment: I think the last one follows the Swift 3 API design guidelines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:**

Depending on whether the `chapter` information is important to distinguish from other methods/meanings, you should use the first or the third option. Not the second option.

> Include all the words needed to avoid ambiguity for a person reading code where the name is used.

> ..., if the first argument forms part of a grammatical phrase, omit its label, appending any preceding words to the base name, e.g. `x.addSubview(y)`

(from [API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#promote-clear-usage))

---

This is not so easy to decide without knowing the class.

Let's consider this is a class:

```
class Book {
    var chapters: [Chapter]
    var pages: [Page]
    var metadata: [MetaData]
}
```

If you look into [Swift Evolution 0005](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md) about the way Obj-C methods are imported, you can learn that the preferred way to import the method `[UIView addGestureRecognizer:]` is `addGestureRecognizer(_:UIGestureRecognizer)`.

Note the rationale:

> If we were to drop GestureRecognizer, leaving just add, we end up with a method that conceptually modifies the gestureRecognizers property but uses an overly generic name to do so.

That's why there is a rule

> Never prune a suffix from the base name of a method that matches a property of the enclosing class:

Your first option is then the correct solution.

On the other hand, if your class has the following form:

```
class Chapters {
   private var chapters: [Chapter]
}
```

(e.g. an array-like container)

Then `add(_:)` is the correct solution.

The second option `add(chapter:)` should never be used.

Answer (score 1):

From the [API Design guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming), the first one seems correct:

```
// Clear
func addChapter(_ chapter: Chapter)
variable.addChapter(x)

// Not clear
func add(chapter chapter: Chapter)
variable.add(chapter: x)

// Not clear
func add(_ chapter: Chapter)
variable.add(x)
```

Note: changed the answer after Sulthan's comment, please refers to his answer.

Comment: The second is not correct from the API Design guidelines you quote.

Comment: I think you are referring to the "Omit needless words", but it depends on the variable type itself: the "Element" in the example is a very generic thing, so the type is specified in the variable name itself - the example provides "cancelButton"; in the case of the answer chapter is not a generic thing, so the variable name will be something not specific like "first", "second" or so: in that case I prefer to provide a context in the method definition.

Comment: I refer to *"Otherwise, if the first argument forms part of a grammatical phrase, omit its label, appending any preceding words to the base name"*

Comment: Oh nice catch! I looked at the Naming Convention rather than Argument Labels. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on situation.

For example, you have User struct.

```
struct User {
    static func add(with userId: String) {
        // ...
    }

    static func addFollower(for userId: String, _ followerId: String) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And when you will use it:

```
User.add(with: newUserId) // Like sentense: User add with new user Id
```

And

```
User.addFollower(for: currentUserId, followerId) // Like sentense: User add follower for current user Id
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would go with

```
func add(chapter: Chapter)
```

This solution seems like the clearest to me.